# firebase functions onCall() got CORS error

Tags: firebase, docker, vue.js, cors

I try to use onCall() from vue app by httpsCallable, under local development.
But I got this error.
What should I do for fix this?

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/AIzaSyBpluKffrfsfscJj2b3E/us-central1/getGreeting' from origin 'http://localhost:3333' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

`firebase  | ✔  functions[us-central1-getGreeting]: http function initialized ( http://127.0.0.1:5002/my-app/us-central1/getGreeting).`
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XVuK.png)

docker-compose.yml
vue
Dorkerfile
vite-app
firebase
Dockerfile
functions
firebase.json

docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
      - 9091:9091 # Firebase Authentication
      - 5002:5002 # Clound Functions
      - 8081:8081 # Cloud Firestore
      - 4001:4001 # Emulator Suite UI
```

Dockerfile

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "cd functions && npm run build & firebase emulators:start"]
```

firebase.json

```
"emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9091
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5002
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8081
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 4001
    }
  },
```

firebase/functions/src/index.ts

```
import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = "localhost:9091";
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = "localhost:8081";

export const getGreeting = onCall(
  { cors: ["http://localhost:3333"] },
  (request) => {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
);
```

vue/vite-app/firebase/firebase.ts

```
const isDevelopment = import.meta.env.DEV;
if(isDevelopment) {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9091');
  connectFirestoreEmulator(database, '127.0.0.1', 8081);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5002);
}
```

test.vue

```
import { httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
import { functions } from '../firebase-auth/firebase-auth';
const test = async () => {
  const data = { key: 'value' }; 
  const helloOnCall = httpsCallable(functions, 'getGreeting');
  const res = await helloOnCall(data);
  console.log(res)
}
```